# How to check the motion of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

does anyone know how to improve this code?
I have this mechaniс : ball player creates a bullet ball in front of him and reduces his size, need to disable the reduction of the player's ball if the bullet is already created and flies forward.
I will be glad to any ideas

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DecreasePlayerBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speedDecrease;
    [SerializeField] private int healthPlayer;
    public GameOver gameOver;

    void Update()
    {
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag("ballBullet").transform.position.z <= 25.3481f)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                Decrease();
                healthPlayer--;

                if (healthPlayer <= 0)
                {
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    gameOver.GameOverScreen();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Decrease()
   {
        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(speedDecrease, speedDecrease, speedDecrease) * Time.deltaTime;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the position of the object in a variable and check if the position changes to check if it has moved or use [Transform.hasChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html) or a boolean of your choice to handle "hasMoved" state.

I'd try something like (not debuggued):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DecreasePlayerBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speedDecrease;
    [SerializeField] private int healthPlayer;
    public GameOver gameOver;
    void Start() {
        transform.hasChanged = false; // its false by default probably
    }
    void Update()
    {
        // if (GameObject.FindWithTag("ballBullet").transform.position.z <= 25.3481f)
        if (!transform.hasChanged) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                Decrease();
                healthPlayer--;

                if (healthPlayer <= 0)
                {
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    gameOver.GameOverScreen();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Decrease()
   {
        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(speedDecrease, speedDecrease, speedDecrease) * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.hasChanged = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the script DecreasePlayerBall is installed on the player's ball, and I need to check exactly the bullet, for this I used GameObject.FindWithTag. but thanks for the idea,

Comment: you can add a reference to the bullet transform in your script and check that transform instead

Comment: I already tried many options, and nothing worked for me, it only works with GameObject.FindWithTag but I know that this is not the best solution. if it's not difficult, could you show an example of how to create a correct reference to a prefab in my case?

Comment: you can add `[SerializeField] private Transform bulletTransform;` in your script and drag the bullet transform in there in the editor

Comment: did you mean to do that?  if (_bullletTransform.position.z == _shotPoint.position.z).  _shotPoint - the point at which the bullet is generated